# What term means the "non-fiction information found in a fictional story"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When one reads a fictional story, one can still learn about non-fiction things. I do not necessarily mean in "creative non-fiction", but this is nearly found in any realistic fiction. For example, by reading one of Fyodor Dostoyevsky's fiction novels, one can discover what society was like in his place and time.

- The nearest word I can find to describe this is "subject matter", but I do not know if this accurately fits.

Is there a term used to describe this "non-fiction information" that can be taken from a story?

Comment: I don't have a word for it, but many people will say things like: *'a well researched and historically accurate depiction of life in ..."*

Comment: Perhaps *transportive* or *realistic*, I would second *(historically) accurate*.

Comment: I am not looking for a term to describe this kind of literature, but a word used to refer to all of this information in the story, preferably as a whole. I want to tell my readers, "While reading the story, play close attention to ___."

Comment: I would call it the *setting* or the *backdrop*.

Comment: While reading the story, pay close attention to the way he's woven historically accurate details throughout.

Comment: Perhaps authenticity or trivia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...pay close attention to the [non-fictive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Non-fictive?s=t) elements.

Comment: You might want to find a better link, that one just calls _non-fictive_ the adverb form of _fictive_.

Answer (score 0):

How about "real-life facts"?  or "historically accurate facts"?

Answer (score 0):

How about *factual information*?

> [**factual**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/factual): of the nature of fact; real; actual; based on facts
>
> *The film, "Stigmata," is based on [**factual**](http://www.scriptologist.com/Magazine/Tips/Stigmata/stigmata.html)
>  elements such as an ancient document called the Gospel of St. Thomas; real life phenomena known as the stigmata; and the experiences of Padre Pio, a priest who possessed the stigmata, the wounds inflicted upon Christ during the crucifixion.*